# Division between two valid float Pandas Series objects returns NaN for some reason

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe object, df, with three columns, "a","b" and "c" where "c" column is a float column.
I use df.loc to extract "c" column value from a specific row in df as the following :

```
data = [['a_1', 'b', 0.188008], ['a_2', 'b', 0.17636]] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df)

     a  b         c
0  a_1  b  0.188008
1  a_2  b  0.176360


c_value_1 = df.loc[(df['a'] == 'a_1') & (df['b'] == 'b')]['c']
c_value_2 = df.loc[(df['a'] == 'a_2') & (df['b'] == 'b')]['c']
print(c_value_1/c_value_2)

0   NaN
1   NaN
Name: c, dtype: float64

print(c_value_1.divide(c_value_2))

0   NaN
1   NaN
Name: c, dtype: float64

print(c_value_1.dtype)

float64

print(c_value_2.dtype)

float64

print(c_value_1)

0    0.188008

print(c_value_2)

1    0.17636
```

When I check the datatype of c_value_1 and c_value_2 by executing "print(c_value_1.dtype), I get "float64" as expected.
Also, printing these two values returns non-zero float values.
However, if I divide c_value_1 by c_value_2 by either

```
c_value_1/c_value_2
```

or

```
c_value_1.divide(c_value_1)
```

I get NaN.
I'm confused why this is happening since when I compute the division using the following code, I get the correct division result:

```
c_value_1.array/c_value_2.array
```

Could someone please shed some light on this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example... what does your df look like?

Comment: Also what's the dtype of your `c_value_2` ? is it also `float`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I updated my post with additional details. And, yes, c_value_2 is float as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are dealing with 2 rows.
0, for which you have a `c_value_1` but no `c_value_2`.
And 1, for which you have a `c_value_2` but no `c_value_1`.

So, when you divide one by another, you get a 2 rows dataframe.
One row, with index 0, and value 0.188008/NaN = NaN
Another row, with index 1, and value NaN/0.17636 = NaN

The problem comes from what is `df.loc[(df['a'] == 'a_value_1') & (df['b'] == 'b_value')]['c']`. It is not a float. It is a series. An "indexed list" of some sort of floats. Containing for each index for which `df['a']` is equal to `a_value_1` and `df['b']` is equal to `'b_value'`, a number found if column `df['c']`. You seem to assume that there is exactly one value. But nothing says that. There could be 0. There could be 10. And more importantly, they are specific row of a specific index.

Same goes for `c_value_2 = df.loc[(df['a'] == 'a_value_2') & (df['b'] == 'b_value')]['c']`. There could be 0 floats in that "indexed list". There could be 10. And more importantly, those you get are specific to an index

See another example

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['x','y','xy'], 'v':[1,2,3]})
```

So `df` is

```
    a  v
0   x  1
1   y  2
2  xy  3
```

I can, as you did, select some rows, and from there, some values `v`

```py
df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('x')]['v']
```

Getting value `v` of rows for which column `a` string value contains the letter 'x' of index 0 and 2.

```
0    1
2    3
Name: v, dtype: int64
```

Likewise,

```py
df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('y')]['v']
```

shows values `v` of rows whose column `a` contains letter `y`, that is rows 1 and 2

```
1    2
2    3
Name: v, dtype: int64
```

So, now, if I add both

```py
df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('x')]['v']+df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('y')]['v']
```

What I get is for every mentioned rows, for index 0, `1+NaN`=`NaN`, for index 1, `NaN+2`=`2`, and for index 2: `3+3`=`6`

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    6.0
Name: v, dtype: float64
```

Think of dataframe a bit like excel tables, and formulas.
In Excel, if you create two columns of cells with a conditional value `c` depending of some criterias in the other columns (and empty cells elsewhere), and then, a third column that is the sum of the 2 others, even if there is exactly one single non empty cell in the 2 created columns, the third (the sum) won't contain the sum of those two numbers, unless they are on the same row.

If you are really positive that your query should return 1 and exactly one value for both queries, then you could get rid of the index

```
df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('x')].reset_index()['v']+df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('y')].reset_index()['v']
```

Returns

```
0    3
1    6
Name: v, dtype: int64
```

Which is 1+2 and 3+3, the sums of the two results returned by each of my two `df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('x')]` and `df.loc[df['a'].str.contains('y')]`, regardless of their index,

But, another note: this is not a database, with index making it very efficient to query a row by some `==` criteria. If you are sure that each of your "query" match a single row, then, probably, you should find another way to query it. Because here (under the hypothesis that this select 1 value), you are building a whose serie of `True/False` values (that contains exactly 1 `True`, and hundred of `False`), and then using that series of boolean to filter the wanted value.

Comment: That's very interesting. So are you saying that row 0 (aka c_value_1 object) has two columns, c_value_1 and c_value_2?

Comment: If I want to extract two distinct rows from an original dataframe and divide them based on a certain column, what's the proper way to do it?

Comment: No, I am not saying that. I am saying that `c_value_1` is a column. Not part of the dataframe. It is just a new "column" that you created. A `series`. Likewise, `c_value_2` is another column. And those column are both indexed using the same index than the one used by dataframe `df`. Any operations between series are performed rows by rows, index by index. So there is not really a row 0 (in pandas, it is columns that are the "main" objects). There are 3 things, a dataframe `df`, and 2 series `c_value_1` and `c_value_2`. That all 3 use the same index.

Comment: Therefore that all 3 can have a row with index 0 (but apparently, they don't. `c_value_1` seems to only have a row with index 312. And `c_value_2` seems to only have a row with index 344. `df` obviously have rows with index 312 and 344, and probably all the other numbers between 0 and 344, and may even more after 344... (but that is speculation on my behalf, since I haven't seen `df`. Just, I know that unless it has a long history, dataframe index usually start boringly from 0 and increase 1 by 1)

Comment: As for your question (how to divide 2 different rows), I've (sort of) replied to that in my answer (but it may have been in the part edited while you were asking). But true answer is "normally you don't do that". That seems to indicate a wrong usage of dataframe. Dataframes are not supposed to be used rows by rows, They are supposed to be for batch operations between whole columns

Comment: Thank you so so much for your detailed answer with examples! After reading your updated answer, I was able to clarify my confusion! Thank you so much!

Comment: Depending on some context, there might be good reasons sometimes to mix different rows. Using transpose, groupby, join, shift, ... are some ways that may end up with combining things from different rows. But then, the context, in those case where it may make sense, also says what is the right way to do it. So, I hope you just don't take by `reset_index()` tip, and use it without examining its pertinence. Dataframe are very inefficient way to store values in rows, in a attribute/value mode